# Is ring automorphism on endomorphism ring of vector space an inner automorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

$\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}$
Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{K}$. Let $\End(V)\overset{*}{\longrightarrow}\End(V)$ be a ring automorphism. I am trying to show that there is a $\theta\in\Aut(V)$ so that
$$T^*=\theta T\theta^{-1}\qquad \forall T\in\End(V)$$
I have figured out that if such a $\theta$ exists then $\theta^*=\theta$ and $\theta^2=\lambda\id_V$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{K}$.

Comment: How did you conclude that $\theta$?

Comment: Set $T=\theta$ to get $\theta^*=\theta$. To get $\theta^2=\lambda id_V$ use that commutator $[T,\theta^*\theta]=0 \quad T\in End(V)$ implies $\theta^*\theta=\lambda id_V$.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying

Comment: @Troposphere $\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}$ $\End(V)\overset{*}{\longrightarrow}\End(V)$ is another way to write $*:\End(V)\to\End(V)$

Comment: OK, I see. $ {} $

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automorphisms of matrix rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2311736/automorphisms-of-matrix-rings). Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. It is an answer for the finite dimensional case.

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}$

$\theta$ exists if $V$ is finite-dimensional.

Fix a non-zero $u\in V$ and $\phi\in V'$ where $V'$ denotes the dual space. Then $u\otimes \phi\in\End(V)$ and is non-zero. Since $*$ is injective $\exists z\in V$ so that $(u\otimes\phi)^*z\neq0$. Define $\theta\in\End(V)$ by $\theta x\equiv (x\otimes\phi)^*z$. Let $T\in\End(V)$.
$$\begin{align*}
\theta T x &=\left((Tx)\otimes\phi\right)^*z \\
&=\left(T(x\otimes\phi)\right)^*z \\
&=T^*(x\otimes\phi)^*z \\
&=T^*\theta x
\end{align*}$$
So $\theta T=T^*\theta$. Let $w\in V$. Since $\theta u\neq0$, by axiom of choice there is a $S\in \End(V)$ so that $S\theta u=w$. Since $*$ is surjective, $S=U^*$ for a $U\in \End(V)$. $U^*\theta u=w$. Since $\theta U=U^*\theta$, $\theta Uu=w$, so $\theta$ is surjective. If $V$ is finite-dimensional, this means $\theta$ is invertible and $T^*=\theta T\theta^{-1}$.