# A linear operator in $Mat_{n\times n}(K)$ preserving multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $D\neq 0$ be a linear transformation from $Mat_{n\times n}(K)$ to $Mat_{n\times n}(K)$ that preserves multiplication: $D(AB)=D(A)D(B)$. Show that there exists nonsingular $C$, such that $D(A)=CAC^{-1}$.

I think we may first show $D(E)=E$ from the fact that $D(A)D(E)=D(A)$ for all $A$, but I have no idea how to show this. Can we show there exist some $A$ such that $D(A)$ is nonsingular?

Any hints are welcomed.

Comment: False if $D \equiv 0$. Otherwise,  what can you about $D(I)$?

Comment: @geetha290krm I think it is idempotent and D(A)D(I)=D(A), but I cannot deduce further. Could you give me more hints? Thank you :)

Comment: Note that $\text{Mat}_{n \times n}(K)$ is a [simple ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/22629/81360). I believe it follows that if $D$ is a non-zero, linear and multiplication-preserving map, then $\ker(D) = \{0\}$. As a result, it follows that $D(E)$ is invertible (I assume you're using $E$ to refer to the identity matrix) and thus $D(E) = E$.

Comment: From there, we could use the fact that [every matrix-ring automorphism is inner](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2311736/81360).

Comment: If you are ok with characteristic $0$ (for now) you can do this with the trace. Recognize composing trace with your linear map $T$ (out of habit I use T instead of D) is a class function and $T(\mathbf e_k\mathbf e_k^T)$ is an idempotent matrix, so its trace is equal to the same $ r \in \mathbb N$ for all k. Then $T(I)$ is an idempotent matrix with trace $=n \cdot r \leq n \implies r$ is zero or one and $T(I)$ is $0$ or $I$ and the former implies $T=0$, so it must be the latter.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you! Your argument is clear!

Comment: @user8675309 Why is $\mathrm{trace}\circ T$ a class function? I think to see this we need $T(A)^{-1}=T(A^{-1})$ first?

Comment: regarding class function: notice that $\text{trace}\big(T(SAS^{-1})\big)=\text{trace}\big(T(S)T(A)T(S^{-1})\big)=\text{trace}\big(T(S^{-1})T(S)T(A)\big)=\text{trace}\big(T(S^{-1}S)T(A)\big)=\text{trace}\big(T(I)T(A)\big)=\text{trace}\big(T(IA)\big)=\text{trace}\big(T(A)\big)$

Comment: My original argument shows $\text{trace}\big(T(\mathbf e_k\mathbf e_k^T)\big)=1$ and now consider the other standard basis vectors for $V$: $\text{trace}\big(T(\mathbf e_k\mathbf e_j^T)\big)=0$ for $j\neq k$ since $\big(T(\mathbf e_k\mathbf e_j^T)\big)^2= \mathbf 0$ i.e. $T(\mathbf e_k\mathbf e_j^T)$ is a nilpotent matrix.  Conclude $\text{trace}\big(A\big)= \text{trace}(T\big(A\big))$ for arbitrary $A\in M_n(\mathbb F)$.  And by non-degeneracy of bilinear (Killing) form $b(A,B)=\text{trace}\big(AB\big)$ conclude $\dim \ker T =0$.

Comment: @user8675309 Thank you! I understand your argument, but it seems that the trace-method does not work when $\mathrm{char}(K)\mid n$.